# Session crash in Colab due to excess usage of RAM

Tags: numpy, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, ram

I'm getting the following runtime error when I tried to create a huge 3D numpy array.
**Your session crashed after using all available RAM.**

This is the code that's causing the error,

```
decoder_output_one_hot = np.zeros((30000, 23, 20000), dtype='float32').
```

Why is this occurring when I can access over 25GB of RAM?

Comment: Essentially, it's math at work. Your data type is `float32` meaning each zero in the array is 32 bits or 4 bytes in size (32/8 = 4). The size of the array is 13,800,000,000 units (30,000 x 23 x 20,000). If you multiply 4 bytes times 13,800,000,000, you come up with 55.2 Gigabytes of size, so you would need access to at least that much RAM for that calculation. You can try adding swap memory to fill in the gaps, but note that swap memory uses hard drive space, so it will fill up your drive and be much slower than RAM, but should work for what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Your are attempting to create an array with 30000 x 23 x 20000 = 13,800,000,000 entries. Each entry is a 32-bit floating point number, so the total number of bytes is 13,800,000,000 x (32 / 8) = 55,200,000,000: in other words, your array would occupy over 50GB in RAM, twice what you have available.